# How can I make a ContourPlot3D with inequality constraints?

Tags: plotting

I need to plot a function in implicit form as below:

```
ContourPlot3D[{73.04 z*y^2 - 293.04 z*x^2 == 
   2605.68 y^2 - 2605.68 x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 15}]
```

but with the constraint `x > y`. How can I do this with *Mathematica*?

Comment: How about `ContourPlot3D[{73.04 z*y^2 - 293.04 z*x^2 == 2605.68 y^2 - 2605.68 x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 15}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x > y]]` ?

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for kindly editing my post again! :)

Comment: @Nasser: Just saw your comment (we must have been typing concurrently) - learned a new one - do you know if it's always the case you can truncate the supplied arguments from a given plot to your `RegionFunction`? (I've not tested this). That is, for CP3D, MM supplies 4 arguments to the function (I was surprised it "matched" a function with only 3 as in your comment), so I'm guessing it wraps the `RegionFunction` specified in a way that some arguments become optional. Thoughts?

Comment: @rasher I just saw in help it used 3 arguments in the examples shown, and that is what I tried. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G9CPJ.png)  I did not know myself one can use 4 arguments like you did.

Comment: @Nasser: Ah! Interesting! In the help for `RegionFunction` itself, it explicitly shows four for CP3D et al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `RegionFunction`, e.g.:

```
ContourPlot3D[{73.04 z*y^2 - 293.04 z*x^2 == 2605.68 y^2 - 2605.68 x^2}, 
              {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 20}, {z, 0, 15}, 
              RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, x > y]]
```

Comment: thank you very much! this also works!