# How to define the plot area to the inside of a circle

Tags: plotting

I dont want the lines not to go beyond the inside of the shown circle but i dont really know how to do it.

`PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}` only sets a rectangular area.

[image]

```
Plot[{{1.2 (-1 + x), -0.9 - 0.5 (-0.18 + x), -0.35 + 2.8 (0.9 x)}, 
  Sqrt[(1 - x^2)],  -Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue},  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Also related to `RegionFunction`: [(32219)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32219/27951) and [(50767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50767/27951)

Answer (score 4):

Use the option [RegionFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionFunction.html):

```
Plot[{{1.2 (-1 + x), -0.9 - 0.5 (-0.18 + x), -0.35 + 2.8 (0.9 x)}, 
  Sqrt[(1 - x^2)], -Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -Sqrt[(1 - x^2)] <= y <= Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or use [ConditionalExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) to restrict the first three functions to the appropriate region:

```
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[1.2 (-1 + x), 
      -Sqrt[(1 - x^2)] <= 1.2 (-1 + x) <= Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]],
   ConditionalExpression[-0.9 - 0.5 (-0.18 + x), 
    -Sqrt[(1 - x^2)] <= -0.9 - 0.5 (-0.18 + x) <=  Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]], 
   ConditionalExpression[-0.35 + 2.8 (0.9 x), 
    -Sqrt[(1 - x^2)] <= -0.35 + 2.8 (0.9 x) <=  Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]],
   Sqrt[(1 - x^2)], -Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
(* same picture *)
```